# Does a local NuGet Gallery deployment require an Azure account?

Tags: nuget, azure-storage

I'd like to run a local NuGet Gallery to serve dependencies to my build system.

I notice in the web.config it asks for Azure details, but the code seems to suggest you can choose 'FileSystem' as a storage backend.

My questions are:

1. If I choose 'FileSystem' how do I configure the target folder?
2. Can I instead point the storage engine at an in-house instance of SQL Server?

I'm trying to avoid using a file system because that's what we are using now with NuGet Server and it's very slow. A couple of the devs like to pack and push every single successful build, so scalability is important.

I hope any answers here will help others, too. For background, here is a great link of setting up your own NuGet Gallery. Sadly, the author has omitted all details pertaining to the actual package storage: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/wiki/Hosting-the-NuGet-Gallery-Locally-in-IIS

Comment: do you have code for nuget gallery ? I want to host it on Azure , do you know the steps ?

Comment: @Neo For the code, follow the link above and clone the git repo

Comment: but it does not have any web project code included nor any web,config configuration

Comment: this is the link I was talking about: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/tree/master/src/NuGetGallery

Comment: I have used same code base getting error:
Command:build\DeployFrontend.cmd
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
D:\home\site\repository\src\NuGetGallery\NuGetGallery.csproj(1513,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them. The missing file is ..\..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets.
An error has occurred during web site deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure File System Package Store:

```html
<appSettings>
  <add key="Gallery:PackageStoreType" value="FileSystem" />
  <add key="Gallery:FileStorageDirectory" value="C:\Path\To\Packages" />
</appSettings>
```

To point to a different SQL Server:

```html
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="NuGetGallery" connectionString="Data Source=SQLSERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=NuGetGallery;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

EDIT: Support SQL Server as Package Store

If you want to store your packages as BLOBs in SQL Server, you'll have to make a couple of changes to the code.

First, create a class named `SqlServerFileStorageService` and implement `IFileStorageService`. This interface has several methods. The important ones are `GetFile()` and `SaveFile()`. Combining `folderName` and `fileName` will create a unique key you can use in your database table.

You can use the same connection string *NuGetGallery* or add a new one for your data access.

You then add an item to the enum `PackageStoreType` called `SqlServer`.

In ContainerBinding.cs add a case for `PackageStoreType.SqlServer` to bind to your `SqlServerFileStorageService`.

Now the NuGet Gallery should create a `SqlServerFileStorageService` and all gets and saves will use your class to store the blob in SQL Server.

BTW: I'm basing this on a cursory look at the code. There may be an extra step or two, but these look like the main areas you'll need to focus on.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Answer 1 is great, though I messed up with #2 by not being specific. I meant: 'can I store the packages themselves in my own SQL instance rather than necessitating an Azure account?'. I know it's frowned upon to store files in SQL but if, for whatever reason, it's better performing to do so I probably would.

Comment: I added instructions on how to do this. You'll need to edit the Gallery code.

Comment: this doesn't look like a massive amount of work - thanks for the suggestion. I'll bash it out at some point and perf test it against the FileSystem storage.